# Mautic installation failed

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mamp, mautic

I am installing Mautic(https://www.mautic.org) following the instructions. 
And I got the following error on the first screen while installing it on localhost.

> Warning:
>   require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mautic/app/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mautic/app/autoload.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   ‘/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mautic/app/../vendor/autoload.php’
>   (include_path=‘.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php’) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mautic/app/autoload.php on line 15

Environment : Mamp 4.1.1

PHP version : 7.1.1

MySQL version : 5.6.35

Looking for your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think their documentation lacks information to install that software properly, please report this as a bug to them

Comment: mostly now installations happen with composer, so if you just zip extraced and tried to run it may not work, try composer install from root directory first to download dependencies then try again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Mautic installation is not properly setup. The vendor error shows that the dependencies cannot be loaded through the vendor folder. Check the vendor folder if it is there on the shown path or not. If it is not there you will need Composer to install the PHP dependencies.

Just use the `composer install` commmand to install all the dependencies. If for some reason you are not able to install dependencies using composer then you also have an option to install a precompiled file from the Mautic site through [this link](https://www.mautic.org/download). Just replace all of the files inside the zip file to the Mautic directory in htdocs.

If you are facing other issues in a different environment you can use these [tutorials](https://pepipost.com/tutorials/tag/mautic/) which can help you to setup those systems.

Comment: You can also try installing using Mautic docker, that way you can avoid these errors.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what instructions are you following?

If you follow the instructions in the GitHub readme, read also the paragraph about [where to download the production-ready package](https://github.com/mautic/mautic#disclaimer), because it seems that you are missing the dependencies in the vendor directory so you've probably downloaded the package directly from GitHub.

If you download that package, you'll need to run `composer install` to install the dependencies yourself, but it's easier and recommended to use the [production package](https://www.mautic.org/download/) on production directly.

I'd recommend to follow this [Basic Setup Guide](https://www.mautic.org/getting-started/).